# "Unexpected call to method or property access" exception for JavaScript load and play method, while playing mp4 video in HTML5 video tag

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-video

I am trying to play a mp4 (in H.264 format) video using HTML5 video tag. It is working fine in Chrome but not in IE-10, 11 and Edge.
Below is the HTML which I have written:

```
<div id="VideoDiv" class="media embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">    
<video id="MyVideo" style="width:100%;height:100%;" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" preload="auto">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    <source ng-src="{{PreviewVideoUrl}}" type="video/mp4" />        
</video>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript code to play the video is:

```
 $uibModalInstance.rendered.then(function () {    
    var video = document.getElementById('MyVideo');       
    video.load();
    video.play();
});
```

Can you please help me to figure out what is going wrong in case of IE browser?

Comment: Is your IE rendering the page in compatibility mode?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I have window 8.1 and IE-11 and it's rendering the page under default i.e. "Edge Default".

Comment: `video.load()` might be causing an error in IE, as `load` is not a function, but an event callback. Can you check the console?

Comment: I commented this peace of code and tried again but no luck..

Comment: You're going to have to do a bit more debugging.

Comment: @JitenderKumar : any luck you fixed this?